# Problem with fgets() and sscanf() in an calculator exercise

Tags: c, scanf, calculator, fgets

I am struggeling with a exercise I have to do. Therefore I have to program a calculater. It only needs to know int and operators like +,-,/ and * and we need to use fgets() and sscanf().

If I enter at first 5+6 for example it works totally fine. As an output I get the correct one: 5+6=11. If my second entry is something like an "a" or "4" it does not print out "invalid input" like it should do. Instead, it prints 4+6=10, so the plus and 6 are automatically added. I think it has something to do with fgets() and its memory but I dont know how to fix this problem.
This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   /* First define the variables, which are needed. 
There are two numbers, type int, and one op for the operation. */
   int number1, number2;
   char operator;
   char entry[50];

   /* First Output, where numbers and Operation are added, after that the code has to scan, which numbers and which operator were choosen.*/

   while (1)
   {
      printf("Enter <int> <op> <int>, single '0' to exit:");
      
      fgets(entry, sizeof(entry), stdin);
      sscanf(entry, "%d %c %d", &number1, &operator, & number2);
   
      /* Different calculations regarding the operator*/

      if (operator== '+')
      {
         printf("%d + %d = %d", number1, number2, number1 + number2);
      }

      else if (operator== '-')
      {
         printf("%d - %d = %d", number1, number2, number1 - number2);
      }

      else if (operator== '*')
      {
         printf("%d * %d = %d", number1, number2, number1 * number2);
      }

      else if (operator== '/')
      {
         printf("%d / %d = %d", number1, number2, number1 / number2);
      }
      else if (number1 == 0)
      {
         printf("Goodbye");
         break;
      }
      else if (number2=="\0" && operator =="\0" ||operator=="\0" )
      {
         printf("invalid input");
      }
      else
      {
         printf("invalid input");
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Example:

Enter   , single '0' to exit:4+5
4 + 5 = 9

Enter   , single '0' to exit:f
4 + 5 = 9

Enter   , single '0' to exit:g
4 + 5 = 9

Enter   , single '0' to exit:6-4
6 - 4 = 2

Enter   , single '0' to exit:7
7 - 4 = 3

Enter   , single '0' to exit:gergevyd
7 - 4 = 3

Comment: Check the return value of `sscanf` and handle the error cases. At the moment you ignore it and just plow on with invalid input values.

Comment: Thanks :) I tried to do that, so I added some more else if statements, but that does not chance something.
It seems like its overwriting or something

Comment: *I tried to do that*. You need to show what you tried. We can't tell if you did it correctly or not unless you show it.

Comment: @Saphira14 If `fgets` returns `NULL` or `sscanf` does not return `3` then you don't have valid inputs so there is no point to `if/else` the values.

Comment: You said you tried it but you did not actually "check the return value of sscanf" as suggested to you.

Comment: Note that when people refer to "the return value of sscanf" they are not talking about the value of the variables whose addresses were passed as parameters.  They are talking about the value returned by the function.  ie, you must do `if( 3 == sscanf(...))`

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having, is as @kaylum points out, you are not validating the result of your conversion. Validations in code are just as critical as implementing correct logic (more so if *Undefined Behavior* results due to the failure to validate)

You must validate EVERY user-input and EVERY conversion. You are doing the right thing taking input with `fgets()`. Using a *line-oriented* function for user-input prevents a large number of problems because you are consuming an entire line of input at once. If the conversion fails later, then you are protected against any erroneous characters remaining in `stdin` unread. (you can employ a check for the `strlen()` of the input and the `'\n'` at the end of what is stored in your `entry` buffer for further validation)

However, you still need to ***check the return*** for `fgets()` because the user canceling input by pressing <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl + z</kbd> on windows) is a valid input that generates a manual `EOF`. So simply check if the return from `fgets()` is `NULL` which will indicate `EOF`, e.g.

```
    ...
    if (!fgets(entry, sizeof(entry), stdin)) {      /* validate EVERY input */
        puts ("(user canceled input)");             /* handle manual EOF case */
        break;
    }
```

With `sscanf()`, you must check that the each valid conversion succeeded and that you did not suffer a *matching-failure* (as entering `'a'` for an integer) or an *input-failure* where `EOF` was reached before the first valid conversion. `sscanf()` returns the number of successful conversions that took place, so just count your *conversion-specifiers* and then make sure the return equals that number, e.g.

```
    /* validate EVERY conversion */
    if (sscanf (entry, "%d %c %d", &number1, &operator, & number2) != 3) {
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        continue;                                   /* go get new input */
    }
    ...
```

(**note:** by using `continue;` on failure you simply cause your program to discard the current line and prompt the user to enter a new one)

---

**Additional Thoughts**

Regarding your login, here are some of my further thoughts (included inline as comments below). When you need a constant, `#define` one (or more). That way you have a convenient location at the top of your code to make changes if required, and you don't have to go picking through declarations or loop limits. When you use `sizeof`, the proper syntax is `sizeof object` or `sizeof (type)`. The parenthesis are only required when you request the size of a `type` (but are not an error in other cases)

Whenever you have a single number or character you are using to determine which, of multiple, branches to take, consider using a `switch()` statement instead a chain of `if .. else if ... else if ... else ...` statements. Much more convenient.

When doing division -- ALWAYS protect against `"divide by zero"` (otherwise bad things happen -- though the code generated will usually handle them as an exception).

When using `fgets()`, you can provide a very simple method for indicating end-of-inputs. Since `fgets()` (as well as POSIX `getline()`) read and store the `'\n'` as part of the buffers they fill, you need only check if the first character in `entry` is `'\n'` to exit (it is a convenient way to go). After your `fgets()` call, you can just check if `*entry == '\n'` to determine if the user is done. (`*entry == *(entry + 0) == entry[0]`) A simple dereference of the pointer is a quick way to check the first character (or first element).

With those in mind, you may consider something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {       /* if no arguments are expected */

    int number1, number2;
    char entry[MAXC], operator;
    
    while (1)   /* loop continually */
    {   /* no special input to exit, break read-loop on blank line */
        fputs ("\n('Enter' to exit)\nEnter expression: int op int: ", stdout);
        
        /* while not EOF or blank line */
        if (!fgets (entry, sizeof entry, stdin) || *entry == '\n') {
            puts ("(user canceled input)");
            break;
        }
        
        /* validate EVERY conversion */
        if (sscanf (entry, "%d %c %d", &number1, &operator, & number2) != 3) {
            fputs ("  error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            continue;                                   /* go get new input */
        }
        
        /* Different calculations regarding the operator*/
        switch (operator)
        {               /* just add \n to end of each format string */
            case '+':   printf ("%d + %d = %d\n", number1, number2, number1 + number2);
                        break;
            case '-':   printf ("%d - %d = %d\n", number1, number2, number1 - number2);
                        break;
            case '*':   printf ("%d * %d = %d\n", number1, number2, number1 * number2);
                        break;
            case '/':
                        if (number2 == 0)   /* handle divide by zero */
                            fputs ("  error: division by 0 exception.\n", stderr);
                        else
                            printf ("%d / %d = %d\n", number1, number2, number1 / number2);
                        break;
            default:    fprintf (stderr, "  error: invalid operator '%c'.\n", operator);
                        break;
        }
    }
}
```

(**note:** the increase in the number of characters `entry` can hold. *Don't skimp on buffer size*. Unless you are on a micro-controller, a 1k buffer is fine and will handle all but the worst times a cat *steps-on-the-keyboard*)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/calculator

('Enter' to exit)
Enter expression: int op int: 1 + 1
1 + 1 = 2

('Enter' to exit)
Enter expression: int op int: 1 + z
  error: invalid integer input.

('Enter' to exit)
Enter expression: int op int: 4 | 8
  error: invalid operator '|'.

('Enter' to exit)
Enter expression: int op int: 10/1
10 / 1 = 10

('Enter' to exit)
Enter expression: int op int: 10/0
  error: division by 0 exception.

('Enter' to exit)
Enter expression: int op int: 25 - 13
25 - 13 = 12

('Enter' to exit)
Enter expression: int op int:
(user canceled input)
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: okay, thanks for your help! I am trying your solution right now...

I am sorry I am just a beginner, I only worked with python before and that was quite different

Comment: No worries, I'm happy to help further, just let me know here if you run into problems.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) it works fine right now. I will now try to catch every user input and look whether i forgot one..If there are any questions, I will ask you, thank you

Comment: @Saphira14 try: `fputs ("\n('Enter' to exit)\nEnter expression: int op int: ", stdout);` for your prompt and then `if (!fgets (entry, sizeof entry, stdin) || *entry == '\n') {...` for your read. Also use a `switch()` to check the operators.

Comment: Also note you are doing *integer* division so `10 / 6 = 0`. You can fix that with `printf ("%d / %d = %.2lf\n", number1, number2, (double)number1 / number2);`

Comment: Thanks again. I looked at your additional thoughts and was able to unterstand it better and learn more. You helped me a lot. I think I unterstand what you meant.

Comment: @Saphira14 - glad it helped. Any more questions, just ask, otherwise, Good luck with your coding!